# setState() callback argument returned a Future. even I didn't mark setState as async

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, setstate, mobile-development

I am working on a food delivery rider application with mvc_pattern. I want to get order details, rider current location and customer delivery address (i-e: Source to destination). I am getting these values by api calls. When I call setState after getting the values, the widget tree is not being rebuilt.
When I debug the code, it says 'setState() callback argument returned a Future.'

```
await getOrderDetailsApi(orderid).then((value) {
      orderDetails = value!;
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(state!.context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(
          S.of(state!.context).notificationWasRemoved,
        ),
      ));
    }).catchError((e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(state!.context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text("This Account Not Exists"),
      ));
    }).whenComplete((){
      final directions = await GooglemapRepo().getDirection(
        origin: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
        destination: LatLng(lat, lng),
      );
      print(directions);
      setState(() {
        info12 = directions;
      });
    });
```

Comment: Your code mixes `await` and `then` and is riddled with `!` operators. Two signs your code is prone to errors. Maybe fix those things and it will get clearer why you get this error.